# Were 14 million abortions performed on African Americans from 1973 to 2006?

Tags: united-states, racism, abortion

The 2006 book [Freed Indeed: The Spiritual Wealth of Black America](https://books.google.com/books?id=hq0-lAazf24C&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=abortions%20of%20blacks%20exceed%20all%20other%20causes%20of%20death&source=bl&ots=Q6YtDXZvEf&sig=EPYtMe4ixFCA5p8X9dWllEgHfEo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNuYTrm_HQAhUK6iYKHY-oB4oQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=abortions%20of%20blacks%20exceed%20all%20other%20causes%20of%20death&f=false) at page 45 says:

> since 1973 over fourteen million black babies have been aborted ... at fourteen million, these abortions exceed all other causes of death of African Americans by over six million

Is this true?

Comment: No.  Quite trivially, because legally & historically there is no death until after a person is born.  Claims to the contrary are purely religious/philosophical/political opinions, and so can't be fact-checked.  Now it would be interesting & perhaps relevant to inquire whether abortion rates for blacks are significantly different from other ethnic groups.

Comment: @jamesqf maybe that's the law where you live, but 
"Homicide is murder in the first degree : If perpetrated without authority of law and with a premeditated design to effect the **death** of the person killed or of **any other human being, including an unborn child**
http://sdlegislature.gov/statutes/DisplayStatute.aspx?Statute=22-16-4&Type=Statute and yes the abortion rate is about 3 times higher for African Americans.

Comment: @jamesqf the rates are in the table 101 here: https://books.google.com/books?id=pW9NAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA70&dq=Abortions%20by%20race%202006&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje49jK6vPQAhUE0oMKHV6uCRQ4ChDoAQgiMAA#v=onepage&q=Abortions%20by%20race%202006&f=false

Comment: @DavePhD: A good example of a political pressure group at work.  Kind of like the ones that keep trying to mandate the teaching of so-called "creation science".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [Trends in the Characteristics of Women Obtaining
Abortions, 1974 to 2004](https://www.guttmacher.org/sites/default/files/report_pdf/trendswomenabortions-wtables.pdf), tables 3 and 4, and [Statistical Abstracts of the United States 2012](https://books.google.com/books?id=pW9NAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA70&dq=Abortions%20by%20race%202006&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje49jK6vPQAhUE0oMKHV6uCRQ4ChDoAQgiMAA#v=onepage&q=Abortions%20by%20race%202006&f=false), table 101, abortion data is as follows:

> year: non-whites (blacks)
>
> 1973: 195,820
> 1974: 269,250
> 1975: 333,000
> 1976: 394,410
> 1977: 427,920
> 1978: 440,190
> 1979: 435,270
> 1980: 460,260
> 1981: 469,570
> 1982: 478,660
> 1983: 490,640
> 1984: 490,550
> 1985: 512,910
> 1986: 529,300
> 1987: 541,800
> 1988: 565,080
> 1989: 546,990  (495,680)
> 1990: 569,890  (505,270)
> 1991: 574,480  (506,790)
> 1992: 585,400  (516,890)
> 1993: 587,280  (517,130)
> 1994: 567,170  (491,590)
> 1995: 542,250  (462,470)
> 1996: 563,300  (482,740)
> 1997:  557,990  (479,360)
> 1998: 557,120  (475,720)
> 1999:  572,240  (484,780)
> 2000:  580,300  (488,040)
> 2001:  574,460  (475,700)
> 2002:  563,170  (467,580)
> 2003:  555,460  (458,320)
> 2004:  548,270  (453,040)
> 2005:  544,000  (452,000)
> 2006:  561,000 (464,000)

In other words, data for blacks aborted was only collected from 1989-2006, during which 8,677,100 were aborted.

Prior to 1989, data for non-whites was lumped together, meaning blacks, Asians and native Americans.  From 1973-1988 this adds to another 7,034,630 aborted, the vast majority (90% based upon 1989 data) of whom were black.

So about **15 million** blacks were aborted in the United States from 1973 to 2006.

And yes, this greatly exceeded all causes of death of blacks in this time period, as seen in table 1 of [Deaths: Final Data for 2014](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/nvsr/nvsr65/nvsr65_04.pdf). Deaths of blacks never exceed 292,808 in any year from 1973-2006.